# what is the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z] /(x^2+y^2+z^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't know how to proceed with these, I have tryed to find prime ideals of this but, I am not sure what is the form of such prime ideals , and then don't now how to find the maximal chain of such prime ideals .

Comment: If all is good, then dividing out by a principal ideal reduces the dimension by $1$. So $2$ is a decent first guess.

Comment: So , if I divide by $(x)$ for example, what happens then? I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: $\Bbb R[x,y,z]/(x)\cong \Bbb R[y,z]$ indeed has Krull dimension 2.

Answer (score 2):

The main argument is that $x^2+y^2+z^2+1$ generates a prime ideal, since it is irreducible in a U.F.D. Also, for any field $k$, $k[x,y,z]$ is a (universally) catenary ring, so for any prime ideal $\mathfrak p\in \operatorname{Spec}k[x,y,z]$, one has
$$\dim(k[x,y,z])=\dim(k[x,y,z]/\mathfrak p)+ \operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak p)=\dim(k[x,y,z]/\mathfrak p)+1.$$

Comment: How can you show that is is irreducible?

Comment: If it were not, it would factor as a product of linear polynomials, and would have roots in $\mathbf R^3$.